# Does calling a CUDA kernel multiple times affect execution speed?

Tags: cuda

I am trying to measure the performance difference of a GPU between allocating memory  using 'malloc' in a kernel function vs. using pre-allocated storage from 'cudaMalloc' on the host. To do this, I have two kernel functions, one that uses malloc, one that uses a pre-allocated array, and I time the execution of each function repeatedly.

The problem is that the first execution of each kernel function takes between 400 - 2500 microseconds, but all subsequent runs take about 15 - 30 microseconds.

Is this behavior expected, or am I witnessing some sort of carryover effect from previous runs? If this is carryover, what can I do to prevent it?

I have tried putting in a kernel function that zeros out all memory on the GPU between each timed test run to eliminate that carryover, but nothing changed. I have also tried reversing the order in which I run the tests, and that has no effect on relative or absolute execution times.

```
const int TEST_SIZE = 1000;

struct node {
    node* next;
    int data;
};


int main() {

    int numTests = 5;

    for (int i = 0; i < numTests; ++i) {
        memClear();
        staticTest();

        memClear();
        dynamicTest();
    }
    return 0;
}

__global__ void staticMalloc(int* sum) {
    // start a linked list
    node head[TEST_SIZE];

    // initialize nodes
    for (int j = 0; j < TEST_SIZE; j++) {
        // allocate the node & assign values
        head[j].next = NULL;
        head[j].data = j;
    }

    // verify creation by adding up values
    int total = 0;
    for (int j = 0; j < TEST_SIZE; j++) {
        total += head[j].data;
    }
    sum[0] = total;
}

/**
 * This is a test that will time execution of static allocation
 */
int staticTest() {

    int expectedValue = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < TEST_SIZE; ++i) {
        expectedValue += i;
    }

    // host output vector
    int* h_sum = new int[1];
    h_sum[0] = -1;

    // device output vector
    int* d_sum;

    // vector size
    size_t bytes = sizeof(int);

    // allocate memory on device
    cudaMalloc(&d_sum, bytes);

    // only use 1 CUDA thread
    dim3 blocksize(1, 1, 1), gridsize(1, 1, 1);

    Timer runTimer;

    int runTime = 0;

    // check dynamic allocation time
    runTime = 0;

    runTimer.start();
    staticMalloc<<<gridsize, blocksize>>>(d_sum);
    runTime += runTimer.lap();

    h_sum[0] = 0;
    cudaMemcpy(h_sum, d_sum, bytes, cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);

    cudaFree(d_sum);
    delete (h_sum);

    return 0;
}

__global__ void dynamicMalloc(int* sum) {

    // start a linked list
    node* headPtr = (node*) malloc(sizeof(node));
    headPtr->data = 0;
    headPtr->next = NULL;

    node* curPtr = headPtr;

    // add nodes to test cudaMalloc in device
    for (int j = 1; j < TEST_SIZE; j++) {

        // allocate the node & assign values
        node* nodePtr = (node*) malloc(sizeof(node));
        nodePtr->data = j;
        nodePtr->next = NULL;

        // add it to the linked list
        curPtr->next = nodePtr;
        curPtr = nodePtr;
    }

    // verify creation by adding up values
    curPtr = headPtr;
    int total = 0;
    while (curPtr != NULL) {
        // add and increment current value
        total += curPtr->data;
        curPtr = curPtr->next;

        // clean up memory
        free(headPtr);
        headPtr = curPtr;
    }

    sum[0] = total;
}

/**
 * Host function that prepares data array and passes it to the CUDA kernel.
 */
int dynamicTest() {

    // host output vector
    int* h_sum = new int[1];
    h_sum[0] = -1;

    // device output vector
    int* d_sum;

    // vector size
    size_t bytes = sizeof(int);

    // allocate memory on device
    cudaMalloc(&d_sum, bytes);

    // only use 1 CUDA thread
    dim3 blocksize(1, 1, 1), gridsize(1, 1, 1);

    Timer runTimer;

    int runTime = 0;

    // check dynamic allocation time
    runTime = 0;

    runTimer.start();
    dynamicMalloc<<<gridsize, blocksize>>>(d_sum);
    runTime += runTimer.lap();

    h_sum[0] = 0;
    cudaMemcpy(h_sum, d_sum, bytes, cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);

    cudaFree(d_sum);
    delete (h_sum);

    return 0;
}

__global__ void clearMemory(char *zeros) {
    int i = threadIdx.x + blockDim.x * blockIdx.x;
    zeros[i] = 0;
}

void memClear() {

    char *zeros[1024]; // device pointers

    for (int i = 0; i < 1024; ++i) {
        cudaMalloc((void**) &(zeros[i]), 4 * 1024 * 1024);
        clearMemory<<<1024, 4 * 1024>>>(zeros[i]);
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < 1024; ++i) {
        cudaFree(zeros[i]);
    }
}
```

Comment: nobody could build your code, right?  Is that your intent?  What sort of timing mechanism are you using?  What is `Timer` and where does it come from?  What OS are you running on?  I'm suspicious because ordinarily host-based timing mechanisms cannot be used reliably to time a CUDA kernel the way you have it written, but I don't know since your code is incomplete.  Try putting a `cudaDeviceSynchronize();` call after each of your kernels, before the timestamp function.  I bet your results will change a lot.

Comment: Also, since you don't appear to be doing any [proper cuda error checking](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14038589/what-is-the-canonical-way-to-check-for-errors-using-the-cuda-runtime-api) in your code at all, I would run your code with `cuda-memcheck` once to make sure there are no execution errors that you are not aware of.

Comment: The timing method you are using is measuring the CPU time not the GPU time. I recommend using Nsight VSE, Visual Profiler, or nvprof to time the kernels. All of the tools are more accurate than home brewed timers.

Comment: Thanks!! The visual profiler is a huge help. And you are dead on: I was measuring CPU time, not GPU time. So the timer calls were out of sync with what was actually happening on the GPU.

Comment: nvprof just used events itself. So you can get the same timings (accuracy wise) using a "home brewed" version. See my answer and the linked article from NVIDIA

Answer (score 1):

The first execution of a kernel takes more time because you have to load a lots of stuff on GPU (kernel, lib etc...). To prove it, you can just measure how long it takes to launch an empty kernel and you will see that it's take some times. Try like:

```
time -> start

launch emptykernel

time -> end

firstTiming = end - start 

time -> start

launch empty kernel

time -> end

secondTiming = end - start
```

You will see that the `secondTiming` is significantly smaller thant the `firstTiming`.

Answer (score 1):

The first CUDA (kernel) call initializes the CUDA system transparently. You can avoid this by calling an empty kernel first. Note that this is required in e.g. OpenCL, but there you have to do all that init-stuff manually. CUDA does it for you in the background.

Then some problems with your timing: CUDA kernel calls are asynchronous. So (assuming your Timer class is a host timer like `time()`) currently you measure the kernel launch time (and for the first call the init-time of CUDA) not the kernel execution time.
At the very least you HAVE to do a `cudaDeviceSynchronize()` before starting **AND** stopping the timer.

You are better of using CUDA events which can exactly measure the kernel execution time and only that. Using host-timers you still include the launch-overhead. See https://devblogs.nvidia.com/parallelforall/how-implement-performance-metrics-cuda-cc/